# Codeigniter HMVC + datamapper

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm facing a problem when I'm using datamapper with codegniter and HMVC module.
It didnt work for MX_CONTROLLER .. c

I have followed these steps: http://stensi.com/datamapper/pages/installation.html
I have created two modules.

Albums_model:

```
<?php
class albums_model extends DataMapper {

    var $has_many = array('photos_model');
    public $table = 'albums';

}
?>
```

And photos_model:

```
<?php
class photos_model extends DataMapper {

    public $table = 'photos';
    public $validation= array(
     array(
        'field' => 'title',
        'label' => 'Title',
        'rules'=>array('required')
    )
);
?>
```

Photos controller:

```
<?php
class Photos extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('photos_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $p=new photos_model();
        $p= $this->photos_model->get();
        print_r($p);
    }
 }
?>
```

Where is the problem? Can anyone help me?

By the way, is there any `$belong_to` option similar to cakephp?

Comment: Please do not confuse [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) pattern with CodeIgniter's ORM that goes by the name of "Datamapper ORM". It implements [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) pattern. Also, please stop referring to instances of ative record as "models". Model is a layer, not a class or object (which is also why what you describe is not even remotely related to MVC).

Comment: Dear tereško,
I didn't understand ? where is the problem with what I described above?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines of code are redundant.

```
$p=new photos_model();
$p= $this->photos_model->get();
```

Based on the examples given here: http://stensi.com/datamapper/pages/gettingstarted.html

I believe you would want to do:

```
$p->get();
```

In place of that second line.

Comment: kayladnls it didnt work..
please note that I'm using MX_CONTROLLER !

Comment: Where are those models stored? 
`Application  
--Controllers  
  Models  
    --HERE?  
  Views  
  Modules  
   Module Name  
   --Controllers  
     Models  
       -- OR HERE?`  

I assume you've verified that you have the correct data in your database? Are you able to get that data via a normal (non Datamapper query)?

Comment: Yeah, I'm able to select the data with a normal query.
I'm using HMVC architecture.
modules
  |--ztest1
      |--controller/c1.php
      |--model/c1_model.php
      |--view/index.php
  |--ztest2
      |--controller/c2.php